# Why does scikit-learn's `precision_score` force the two input to be of the same size?

Tags: scikit-learn

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), precision is:

> tp / (tp + fp)

So why does it matter to scikit's [precision_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) that the y_true and y_pred be of the same size?

Comment: I was trying to compare this with the NLTK version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precision_score()` works by taking the paired `y_true` and `y_pred`, and uses the pairings to determine which are the true positives and false positives in the test samples provided.

Example

```
y_true    y_pred
     0         0   <- True negative
     1         0   <- False negative
     0         1   <- False positive
     1         1   <- True positive
```

Comment: Ah okay, but in the docs it insinuates that it uses the formula; that is wrong?

Comment: No. The formula is `tp`, the number of pairs that are true positives, and `fp` which is the number of pairs that are false negatives.

Comment: No, I mean, the formula counts the true positives etc., we can do this even if y_true and y_pred are not of the same length.

Comment: If they are not the same length, then you have predictions without a corresponding true label, or you would have labels with no corresponding prediction. In either case, you would not be able to call them a "true positive" or a "false positive."

Comment: Well if you know the y_pred then you can do a simple `y_true.intersection(y_pred)` to find out all of those values. But I guess the function isn't doing it that way. It is doing a simple comparison and count, unlike the NLKT version of `precision` which does it that way. I think I understand know. Cheers!

Comment: After reading the NLTK version, your question makes more sense. The NLTK version is designed to work on sets of items, where the scikit-learn version works on ordered examples.